# disable a module in prestashop without admin panel

Tags: javascript, module, prestashop

I installed HTMLbox module, in order to add ZENDESK Chat widget.

After saving widget script. The page www.dulzuria.com CRASHED.

I can no longer access the site, neither the admin panel.

I know that in Wordpress it's enough to change the plugin name in order for the plugin not to be loaded. What is the procedure to disable / unhook a module in prestashop without having access to admin panel using FTP?

Thanks

Comment: The page is up now, have you fixed your problem?

Comment: I think something must have gone wrong with the hosting provider. Thankfully it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must have been a hosting problem, since it's properly working now.

However, I fiddled with a local prestashop installation, and I noticed that disabling from FTP can be done in prestashop as it can be done in wordpress. This is by changin it's name. For example by adding _old to module's name, we won't find it any longer in our module list.

I guess this answers my question.